# Get the label of a product tax rate in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, tax-rate

I need to find out the label of the tax rate in WooCommerce.

With the following code I can find out the tax rate:

```
$taxclass = $product_variation->get_tax_class();
 $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates( $taxclass );
if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
    $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);
    $tax_rate_info = (int)$tax_rate['rate'];
}
else {
}
```

Unfortunately I can not get the exact label of that tax rate. I have tried the following:

```
 $tax_labels = WC_Tax::get_rate_label( $taxclass );
```

I need to somehow find out the id of the tax rate and pass the id to the get_rate_label() so it functions. Can somebody please help how to find the tax rate id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the label name of a specific tax rate using the array key **`label`** as follow:

```
$variation_tax_class  = $product_variation->get_tax_class();
$variation_tax_rates  = WC_Tax::get_rates( $variation_tax_class );

foreach( $variation_tax_rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
    if ( ! empty($rate) ) {
        $rate_percent  = (int) $rate['rate'];
        $rate_label    = $rate['label']; // <== HERE is the label name of the tax rate
        $rate_shipping = $rate['shipping'];
        $rate_compound = $rate['compound'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works. I see you have also added $rate_shipping and it return yes. Is there a way to also get the shipping class and the rate in Euro